# Mssql IN clause @VARIABLE IN ('400','300','406')

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

**In MySQL I can this**

```
SET @CODE_II = '400';
SELECT IF(@CODE_II IN ('R0A','401','407'),'OK','NO');
```

**How can I do this but in mssql-2008?**

```
DECLARE @CODE_II VARCHAR(5);
SET @CODE_II = '400';
SELECT IIF(@CODE_II IN ('R0A','401','407'),'OK','NO');--No working
```

Comment: I am using sql server 2017 and can't duplicate a failure using your script. What is the result in 2012? Do you get an error message or an unexpected result?

Comment: `IIF()` is not standard SQL.

Comment: the error it's solved. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a `CASE` statement:

```
DECLARE @CODE_II VARCHAR(5);
SET @CODE_II = '400';
SELECT CASE WHEN @CODE_II IN ('R0A', '401', '407') THEN 'OK' ELSE 'NO' END
```

Comment: Thanks, in reality the problem lies in the ternary operator IIF

Comment: @WITO . . . This is standard SQL and should work in any database.